# how to define idempotent behaviour incase of stateful operations?

Tags: java, rest, http, idempotent

In several occasionS people claims something was 'idempotent' because it wasn't stateful in-memory, even though its consumer effect was recording transactions.

If reading capabilities don't have to be idempotent,  `getNextIterator()` is a reading capability that isn't idempotent as it would increment the iterator.  A banking request for a balance wouldn't be idempotent as the request would create an audit log.  The returned result might be the same for two subsequent calls (if not changes have happened) but the log entry would be different.

Comment: obviously, every action will have *some* side effect. the issue is whether the side effect is important, which is subjective.

Comment: 'Idempotent' means that the transaction can be repeated without altering the defined result of executing the transaction once: for example, a bank balance.

Comment: Idempotency as regards to REST does not mean multiple requests must result in identical action on the server. GET/PUT in REST should be idempotent only from the view of the client - meaning multiple requests very well may result in vastly different actions (logging, audit) on the server. The client need not know about or consider these actions.

Answer (score 2):

Saying that "logs were created means it isn't stateless" is absurd. Is a call to the server that does nothing "stateful" because a tiny amount of power was used and so your power bill for the month will be a tiny bit higher than it would have been if the call had not been made? No.

Statefulness includes all aspects that matter to the transaction (in-memory, persistent storage, calls to other services, etc). "Idempotent" means that the call may be retried without ill side effects.

Your example of ticking a counter may still be considered idempotent if it doesn't change the business effect of the call or its response to the caller.

Changes internal to the call, that doesn't have any real impact to the business process concerned and that aren't exposed to the caller, are irrelevant to the caller.